# Can I convert a TensorFlow tensor to a CSV file?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, preprocessing

I'm working on a semantic segmentation problem. I have saved my images in a tensor of shape (4767, 192, 192, 3) [It contains 4767 images of size 192*192 with RGB channels]. On the other hand, I have another tensor of masks with shape (4757, 192, 192, 14). It corresponds to 4767 masks of size 192*192 with 14 classes encoded in one-hot encoding.

I want to convert these tensors to CSV format, but I'm not sure how to do it. Is this possible? Does it make sense? Does it involve any loss of information?

Thank you all very much.

Comment: It is always possible. But why? And can you picture what the CSV should look like?

Comment: I am working on a project with raster images. My server does not have gdal, rasterio, or libraries installed to easily process these images, which I need in my processing pipeline. I also don't have administrator permissions to install them. One solution I had thought of is to convert these images to tensors on my local computer and store these tensors in a CSV file. I wasn't sure if it made sense because I'm not exactly sure how the file should look. I suppose I would need to flatten the tensors and convert them into 2D matrices?

Comment: If all you need is to save a TF object (model, variable etc.) as file and read it back on another machine, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63514745/how-to-just-save-tensor-not-models-in-tensorflow2).